What does Canon Law say about tabernacle placement?
I went to a church recently and the tabernacle was not placed in the center (the apse), nor to the side (the transept), nor anywhere within the nave, chancel, etc. Rather, the tabernacle was placed in a separate room east of the north transept where it could not be seen from the nave or sanctuary. I actually had to ask someone where it was located because I couldn't not find it.
This seems wrong to me, so I privately confronted the celebrant after mass. He told me that he's been trying to have the tabernacle moved back to the apse but that he cannot do it without the bishop's permission. I think he was lying to me because 1) the bishop in our diocese is conservative and very supportive of Eucharistic reverence, and 2) a new priest was recently assigned to our local parish and his first day on the job he moved the tabernacle to the apse.
I would like to learn what the Church's official teachings are concerning this matter. Was the priest lying to me? What does Canon Law require for tabernacle placement?

Related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/78585/6071

What does Canon Law say about tabernacle placement?

Accordingly, the "Instruction on the Worship of the Eucharistic Mystery" (1967 issued regulations (later incorporated into the new "Code of Canon Law") concerning tabernacles (cf. No. 52-57 and Canons 934 944): The holy Eucharist may be reserved only on one altar or one place in any church, and a vigil lamp must bum at all times to indicate and honor the presence of our Lord in the Blessed Sacrament. This tabernacle must be immovable, made of solid and opaque material, and locked to prevent theft or desecration of the Blessed Sacrament. The tabernacle "should be placed in a part of the Church that is prominent, conspicuous, beautifully decorated, and suitable for prayer" (Canon 938).
Location of the tabernacle in Catholic churches?

To be crystal clear here is what Canon Law has to say:

Can. 938 §1. The Most Holy Eucharist is to be reserved habitually in only one tabernacle of a church or oratory.
§2. The tabernacle in which the Most Holy Eucharist is reserved is to be situated in some part of the church or oratory which is distinguished, conspicuous, beautifully decorated, and suitable for prayer.
§3. The tabernacle in which the Most Holy Eucharist is reserved habitually is to be immovable, made of solid and opaque material, and locked in such a way that the danger of profanation is avoided as much as possible.
§4. For a grave cause, it is permitted to reserve the Most Holy Eucharist in some other fitting and more secure place, especially at night.
§5. The person responsible for the church or oratory is to take care that the key of the tabernacle in which the Most Holy Eucharist is reserved is safeguarded most diligently.


I'm Orthodox but I can help.
What I found on this issue:
This document is called General Instruction of the Roman Missal and was published in 1969.

314. In accordance with the structure of each church and legitimate local customs, the Most Blessed Sacrament should be reserved in a tabernacle in a part of the church that is truly noble, prominent, readily visible, beautifully decorated, and suitable for prayer.
The one tabernacle should be immovable, be made of solid and inviolable material that is not transparent, and be locked in such a way that the danger of profanation is prevented to the greatest extent possible. Moreover, it is appropriate that, before it is put into liturgical use, it be blessed according to the rite described in the Roman Ritual.
315. It is more in keeping with the meaning of the sign that the tabernacle in which the Most Holy Eucharist is reserved not be on an altar on which Mass is celebrated. Consequently, it is preferable that the tabernacle be located, according to the judgment of the Diocesan Bishop,
a. either in the sanctuary, apart from the altar of celebration, in a form and place more appropriate, not excluding on an old altar no longer used for celebration;
b. or even in some chapel suitable for the faithful's private adoration and prayer and which is organically connected to the church and readily visible to the Christian faithful.
The Place for the Reservation of the Most Holy Eucharist. Chapter V.

You can read the entire document at United States Conference of Catholic Bishops-Chapter V: The Arrangement and Ornamentation of Churches for the Celebration of the Eucharist.
